# Random draws in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have doubt on the following:

(1) I have to simulate a model in Matlab where at a certain point a particular step (a) is perfomed if the realisation of a random variable `U` is positive, where `U` is positive with probability `p`.

(2) The solution adopted in the book is drawing uniformly at random a number `u` from `[0,1]` and perform step (a) if `u<= p_r`.

**What is the link from (1) to (2)? Why (2) is equivalent to (1)? Or, under which assumptions (2) is equivalent to (1)?**

Comment: It is always equivalent. The probability of a uniform [0,1] variable being greater than `p` is `p`. Just compute the integral of the pdf from `0` to `p`: it gives `p`. Since `U` is positive with probability `p` as well, the events have the same probability

Comment: @LuisMendo Thanks there was an error in my question: in (2) I perform step (a) if u<=pr. Also in your answer it should be "The probability of a uniform [0,1] variable being smaller than p is p". Thanks!

Comment: You are right, it is as you say. To make (1) and (2) equivalent you should take `p=p_r` then